# Permissions Needed For DMS Source and Target Databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-dms, aws-rds-data-service

I am working on a AWS DMS Proof of Concept project where I need to migrate a large data set from source to target.I am successful to create the resources and do the migration but the issue I am facing is with permissions created for these database. The source and target both are MySQL Aurora databases and I am creating these databases using the terraform in AWS. When creating users for the databases, I am creating reader, writer and admin. Currently, I am using admin credentials with All Privileges for this. Sample as below:

```
variable "mysql_source_database_roles" {
  description = "Map of database roles and associated permissions."
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    poc-source-db_reader = {
      database   = "poc-source-db"
      privileges = ["SELECT"]
    }

    poc-source-db_writer = {
      database   = "poc-source-db"
      privileges = ["SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE", "DELETE"]
    }
    poc-source-db_admin = {
      database   = "poc-source-db"
      privileges = ["ALL PRIVILEGES"]
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, what privileges can I set for the new user that I create such that DMS works as expected. I have same question for target database user as well.

Answer (score 1):

AWS DMS needs special permissions for users used by the AWS DMS endpoint connectors.

For the source you will need **REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, SUPER** permissions. You could review all details on the link below.

[Using any MySQL-compatible database as a source for AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html#CHAP_Source.MySQL.Prerequisites)

For the target you will need **ALTER, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT ON .***. You could review on link below all details.

[Using any MySQL-compatible database as a target for AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.MySQL.html#CHAP_Target.MySQL.Prerequisites)